# Two floated spans inside li a

Tags: list, css-float, html

Trying to style a few li's in a calendar but having a bit of bother creating two columns inside an li.

Notice the orange does not fill up the area and the two spans do not align...

http://jsfiddle.net/qN4Tp/3/

```
<ol>
    <li>
        <a href="#">
            <span class="event-time">12:00pm</span>
            <span class="event-name">Retail sales grew at their fastest pace in seven years during July, according to the latest data from the British Retail Consortium and KPMG. Sales were up 2.2% year-on-year, driven by…
</span>
        </a>
    </li>
</ol>
```

Comment: I'm  not sure your title is correct. Are you having trouble floating spans, not divs?

Answer (score 1):

This CSS might help you.

Add an attribute to li. Just add **overflow:hidden**. And reduce the width of the event_name class. Thats all :)

```
ol { width: 83%;  margin:0; }
li { line-height: 1.2; margin: 0; padding: 5px; list-style-type: none; background: #d4481b; border:1px solid ; color: #ccc; overflow:hidden}
a { text-decoration: none; line-height:1.2}
.event-time { width: 20%; float: left; display:inline}
.event-name { width: 70%; float: left; display:inline}
```

Here this is the fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/JPrqT/

Comment: This was the solution I was looking for! Before using overflow:hidden, images and spans I was floating did not stay bound within the li tags. An additional tip: to make your span containing text fit the text width use `width: auto`.